# How to remove AngularJS code completion/suggestion from VS Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using Angular 6 instead of AngularJS. But VS Code keeps suggesting me AngularJS code completion.

[image]

The first is AngularJS syntax and the second is Angular 6 syntax.

Where can I disable these AngularJS suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out it was a internal setting of VS Code.

Simply added: 
`"html.suggest.angular1": false`
to my user settings.